# Parsing states in a string in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse `string` to make state info which has the input and which state to go to when it receives the info

example on input given `i{OPEN}a{LOCKED}s{n{OPEN}t{i{PUSH}d{CLOSED}}t{i{PULL}d{OPEN}}t{i{TURN}d{OPEN}}}s{n{CLOSED}t{i{PUSH}d{CLOSED}}t{i{PULL}d{OPEN}}t{i{TURN}d{LOCKED}}}s{n{LOCKED}t{i{PUSH}d{LOCKED}}t{i{PULL}d{LOCKED}}t{i{TURN}d{CLOSED}}}`

`s{...} describes state. All information related to this state is inside pair of braces.`

`s{ n{xxx}...}} inside state scope describes state name xxx.`

`s{ n{xxx} t{...}} inside state scope describes transition from this state to another. There can be several transitions for the state.`

`s{ n{xxx} t{i{...}...}} i inside transition scope describes input value for this transition to happen.`

`s{ n{xxx} t{i{...} d{...}}} d inside transition scope describes destination state of this transition.`

`i{xxx} describes name of initial state`

`a{xxx} describes name of accepting state`

trying to split the different states like this:

```
split states: s{n{OPEN}t{i{PUSH}d{CLOSED}}t{i{PULL}d{OPEN}}t{i{TURN}d{OPEN}}}
split states: s{n{CLOSED}t{i{PUSH}d{CLOSED}}t{i{PULL}d{OPEN}}t{i{TURN}d{LOCKED}}}
split states: s{n{LOCKED}t{i{PUSH}d{LOCKED}}t{i{PULL}d{LOCKED}}t{i{TURN}d{CLOSED}}}
```

`the d/i can be anywhere in the t`

```
s{n{CLOSED}t{d{CLOSED}i{PUSH}}t{i{PULL}d{OPEN}}t{i{TURN}d{LOCKED}}}
```

in first t{} they are switched as an example

the i/a can also be anywhere outside of the s{} so they could be in-between two different states so i cant hardcode anything

```
class Transition
{
public:
  std::string input;
  std::string destination;
  Transition(std::string i, std::string d)
  {
    input = i;
    destination = d;
  }
};

class State
{
public:
  std::string name;
  std::vector<Transition> transitions;
  State(std::string n)
  {
    name = n;
  }
  void addTransition(std::string input, std::string destination)
  {
    Transition transition(input, destination);
    transitions.push_back(transition);
  }
  void displayInfo()
  {
    // display info about state name and transitions for that state
    std::cout << "\nState name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Transitions: " << std::endl;
    for (auto i : transitions)
    {
      std::cout << "Input: " << i.input << " Destination: " << i.destination << std::endl;
    }
  }
};
```

have this so far as the function that does it:

```
void parseAndPopulateStates(std::string input, std::vector<State>& states) {
    
    std::string stateName;
    std::string transitionInput;
    std::string destinationState;
    bool stateFound = false;
    bool transitionFound = false;
    bool destinationFound = false;
    std::string s;
    int open = 0;
    int closed = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        int j = i;
        if (input[j] == 's' && input[j+1] == '{'){
          while (open != closed || open == 0){
            if (input[j] == '{'){
              open++;
            }
            if (input[j] == '}'){
              closed++;
            }
            s += input[j];
            j++;
          }
          std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
          splitStates.push_back(s);
          open = 0;
          closed = 0;
          s = "";
          std::cout<<"eee"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < splitStates.size(); i++){
        std::cout<<"split states: "<<splitStates[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        if(input[i] == 's'){
            if(input[i+1] == '{'){
                i = i+2;
                while(input[i] != '}'){
                    stateName += input[i];
                    i++;
                }
                std::cout<<"State name: "<<stateName<<std::endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++){
                    if(states[i].name == stateName){
                        stateFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!stateFound){
                    State state(stateName);
                    states.push_back(state);
                }
                stateName = "";
                stateFound = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++){
        std::cout<<"vector: "<<states[i].name<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        if(input[i] == 's'){
            if(input[i+1] == '{'){
                i = i+2;
                while(input[i] != '}'){
                    stateName += input[i];
                    i++;
                }
                std::cout<<"State name: "<<stateName<<std::endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++){
                    if(states[i].name == stateName){
                        stateFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!stateFound){
                    State state(stateName);
                    states.push_back(state);
                }
                stateName = "";
                stateFound = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs this (not really worried about the n{ for state name)

```
State name: n{OPEN
State name: n{CLOSED
State name: n{LOCKED

State name: n{OPEN
Transitions:

State name: n{CLOSED
Transitions:

State name: n{LOCKED
Transitions:
```

the expected output should look like this

```
State name: OPEN
Transitions:
Input: PUSH Destination: CLOSED
Input: PULL Destination: OPEN
Input: TURN Destination: OPEN

State name: CLOSED
Transitions:
Input: PUSH Destination: CLOSED
Input: PULL Destination: OPEN
Input: TURN Destination: LOCKED

State name: LOCKED
Transitions:
Input: PUSH Destination: LOCKED
Input: PULL Destination: LOCKED
Input: TURN Destination: CLOSED
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The missing question is "how do I turn the input string into a parse tree that I can then use to construct State and Transition objects".

Comment: wanting to try get the expected output with the given input and classes but ive tried quite a few things and i cant get it to work

Comment: You should show the "quite a few things you tried and cannot get to work" and ask for help on those, instead of a "here is the assignment please help" question

Comment: adding now what i have so far and the output

Comment: Your first step is to extract the state tags from the input string .. why don't you continue using those?

Comment: Are you trying to create a parser? You may need to define a grammar.

Comment: Why invent your own parser when you can store all your data in say yaml, json or xml? Then you can use tested libraries and focus on the functional part of your code.

Comment: the entire code needs to generate a FSM c++ file so i want the values stored in the code itself

Answer (score -7, accepted):

oh yea m8 was ezpz dont know how ya dident see it. but its alguds.

```
void parseInput(const std::string &input, std::vector<State> &states)
{
  std::stack<State> stateStack;
  State currentState;

  std::cout << "\n\nParse input\n\n\n"
            << std::endl;

  char insideState = '_';

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
  {
    char c = input[i];
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
      std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "^" << std::endl;
    std::cout << insideState << std::endl;

    if (insideState == 's')
    {
      if (c == 'n')
      {
        i++; // skip n
        i++; // skip {
        std::string stateName = "";
        while (input[i] != '}')
        {
          stateName += input[i];
          i++;
        }
        currentState.setName(stateName);
        std::cout << "State name: " << stateName << std::endl;
      }
      else if (c == 't')
      {
        insideState = 't';
      }
      else if (c == '}')
      {
        stateInfo.push_back(currentState);
        currentState = State();
        insideState = '_';

        std::cout << "State added" << std::endl;
      }
      continue;
    }

    else if (insideState == 't')
    {
      std::string inputName = "";
      std::string destinationName = "";

      while (c != '}')
      {
        if (c == 'i')
        {
          i++; // skip i
          i++; // skip {
          while (input[i] != '}')
          {
            inputName += input[i];
            i++;
          }
          std::cout << "Input name: " << inputName << std::endl;
        }
        else if (c == 'd')
        {
          i++; // skip d
          i++; // skip {
          while (input[i] != '}')
          {
            destinationName += input[i];
            i++;
          }
          std::cout << "Destination name: " << destinationName << std::endl;
        }

        i++;
        c = input[i];
      }
      currentState.addTransition(inputName, destinationName);
      insideState = 's';

      std::cout << "Transition added" << std::endl;

      continue;
    }

    else if (c == 'i')
    {
      // skip
      while (input[i] != '}')
      {
        i++;
      }
    }

    else if (c == 'a')
    {
      // skip
      while (input[i] != '}')
      {
        i++;
      }
    }

    else if (c == 's')
    {
      insideState = 's';
    }
  }
}
```

spits out this
State name: OPEN
Transitions:
Input: PUSH Destination: CLOSED
Input: PULL Destination: OPEN
Input: TURN Destination: OPEN

State name: CLOSED
Transitions:
Input: PUSH Destination: CLOSED
Input: PULL Destination: OPEN
Input: TURN Destination: LOCKED

State name: LOCKED
Transitions:
Input: PUSH Destination: LOCKED
Input: PULL Destination: LOCKED
Input: TURN Destination: CLOSED

hope thats wat ur looking 4.
stuff the guys in the comments they dont no whgat there talking about